# ODBC Doesn't want to connect with pdo

Tags: php, odbc

I'm currently trying to make a connection between an SQL server and php website. I tried with odbc_connect and everything is working "fine" but i would like to use "PDO" but i have an error with it.

```
    $server = 'SRV';
    $database = 'NOUVO_DB';
    $user = 'tUSERNAME';
    $password = 'XXXXX';

    $connection = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=$server;Database=$database;", $user, $password);
    print_r($connection);

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM personnelVisiteur';
    $result = odbc_exec($connection, $sql);  //returns data

    while(odbc_fetch_row($result)){

        for($i=1;$i<=odbc_num_fields($result);$i++){
            echo "Result is ".odbc_result($result,$i) .'<br>';
        }
    }

    echo '<h1>PDO:</h1>';

    try { 
        $pdo_con = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}", $user, $password);
        print_r($pdo_con);
    } catch (PDOException $exception) { 
      echo $exception->getMessage(); 
      exit; 
    }
```

Output :

```
ODBC CONNECT:

Resource id #2

PDO:
SQLSTATE[HY090] SQLConnect: 0 [Microsoft][Gestionnaire de pilotes ODBC] Longueur de cha�ne ou de m�moire tampon non valide =>  Invalid string or buffer length
```

Thanks.

Maybe an error with 64bits server ?

Answer (score 0):

That was my bad, i guess :

If anyone has an issue :

```
$pdo_con = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};server=$server;database=$database", $user, $password);
```

You need to specify in first param :
**"odbc:Driver{DRIVER NAME};server=$server;database=$database"**